# What Puppet modules do include best practices regarding CI and rspec-puppet like Geerlingguy's Ansible roles?

Tags: ansible, puppet, rspec-puppet

It is possible to test Puppet code using rspec-puppet, but modules that are supported by the community like [NTP](https://github.com/puppetlabs/puppetlabs-ntp) do not seem to run test regularly like is done for all Geerlingguy's Ansible roles, e.g. [Apache](https://github.com/geerlingguy/ansible-role-apache).

The aim is to find a Puppet module on Github that shows the best practices regarding testing using rspec-puppet on build using a CI like Travis. When such a module is found one could read and understand the .travis.yml and apply it to custom modules.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to https://forge.puppet.com and look for modules with a high "Quality Score"

For example https://forge.puppet.com/puppetlabs/stdlib/scores.

Then you can take a look at the Project URL and view it's .travis.yml and the tests in spec/